# Integer solutions for the equation $2r = q^{r-1}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-diophantine-equations

I want to find all the integer solutions for the following equation $2r = q^{r - 1}$ for $r\geq 1$ and $q$ an integer i.e., $q=2k$ for some natural number k not equal to zero.

I know that we should the ln function on both sides of the equation but how I will get the only solutions $q=4$ when $r=2$ and $q=2$ when $r=4$.

Could someone explain this to
me please?

Comment: @Mike The OP showing some (slight) effort, I didn't feel like downvoting (which I do very often, sometimes perhaps too severely). I agree it was easy and kind of usual, but didn't succeed in finding some convenient post to link, for voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @AnneBauval it was really a matter of the question being too easy and not much effort demonstrated. But it is a clear downvote for me [sorry to have to say OP].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $2r = q^{r - 1}$ for some natural numbers $r\ge1$ and $q$ then $r\ge2$, $q=2k$ for some integer $k\ge1$, and $$r=2^{r-2}k^{r-1}.$$

- For $r=2$, the solution is $k=2$, i.e. $q=4$.
- For $r=3$, there is no solution.
- For $r=4$, the solution is $k=1$, i.e. $q=2$.
- For $r\ge5$, there is no solution because $r<2^{r-2}$.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: Thanks to you and the 2 other upvoters of yesterday. Why these downvotes today? (1 on my answer and 1 on your question)

Comment: I didn't upvote or downvote your answer. I did downvote the question though, these types of Diophantine questions have been asked here many times, and this one was particularly easy.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $q>1$ and so $r=\frac{q^{r-1}}{2}\geq2^{r-2}$, which implies $r\leq4$.